# Reverse C++11 range-based for loop

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I wrote this snippet:

```
template <typename ContainerT>
class ReverseIterator
{
public:
    ReverseIterator(ContainerT& iContainer) : m_container{iContainer}
    {

    }

    typename ContainerT::reverse_iterator begin()
    {
        return m_container.rbegin();
    }

    typename ContainerT::reverse_iterator end()
    {
        return m_container.rend();
    }

private:
    ContainerT& m_container;
};

template <typename ContainerT>
auto Reverse(ContainerT& iContainer)
{
    return ReverseIterator<ContainerT>(iContainer);
}
```

To be able to do something like this:

```
std::vector<int> myList{1, 2, 3};
for (auto& itr : Reverse(myList))
{
    ++itr;
}
```

First I'd like a feedback up to this point.

Then, I'd like to be able to write something like this:

```
for (auto itr : Reverse(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3}))
{
    std::cout << itr << " ";
}
```

Without having a separate and near identical implementation of `ConstReverse`.

I thought about making everything with forwarding references but for some reason that didn't work out very well and I'm not exactly sure where I was mistaken. Could someone show me how it could be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good clear template code - well done!

I'd consider changing the name, as the class itself isn't an iterator, it's an iterator pair, or *range*, that wraps a *container* and provides a reversed *view* of it.

Constructor should be `explicit`.

We should use free-function `rbegin()` and `rend()` to give us greater flexibility of container types (e.g. C-style arrays) - fall back to the `std` versions in `<iterator>` if argument-dependent lookup fails.

It could be improved by overloading `Reverse` with a version that accepts a `const Container`:

```
template <typename ContainerT>
auto Reverse(const ContainerT& iContainer)
{
    return ReverseIterator<const ContainerT>(iContainer);
}
```

For this to work properly, we need to change the return type of `begin()` and `end()` to `auto`, so that we get `const_reverse_iterator` back from them.  If you're really stuck with C++11, then we'll have to add the trailing return type: `auto begin()-> decltype(m_container.begin())`, for example.  For my own convenience, I'll work with C++17 from here onwards.

---

Applying these suggested changes gives us:

```
template <typename ContainerT>
class ReverseContainerView
{
public:
    explicit ReverseContainerView(ContainerT& iContainer)
      : m_container{iContainer}
    {
    }

    auto begin() {
        using std::rbegin;
        return rbegin(m_container);
    }
    auto end() {
        using std::rend;
        return rend(m_container);
    }

private:
    ContainerT&  m_container;
};


template<typename ContainerT>
auto Reverse(ContainerT& iContainer)
{
    return ReverseContainerView<ContainerT>(iContainer);
}

template<typename ContainerT>
auto Reverse(const ContainerT& iContainer)
{
    return ReverseContainerView<const ContainerT>(iContainer);
}
```

and demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    auto list = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3};
    for (auto& i: Reverse(list)) {
        std::cout << ++i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    for (const auto& i: list) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    const auto const_list = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3};
    for (auto i: Reverse(const_list)) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

---

Note that the proposed usage `for (auto i: Reverse(std::vector<int>{10, 20, 30}))` (where the constructor argument is an xvalue) won't work with the above code.  That's because the temporary has gone out of scope after the `ReverseContainer` was constructed but before the `for` loop completes, leaving a dangling reference in the container.  We'll need a version that captures and stores any rvalue type passed to it.

The easiest way I know to do this is to split the class into its two responsibilities: a base class to capture the wrapped container and a subclass to access the reversed view (we might want to put some or all of these classes into an inner namespace to hide them from users; I'll leave that question open here).

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, bool CopyValue = !std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>>
struct ContainerContainer;

template <typename T>
struct ContainerContainer<T, false>
{
    // lvalue version: contains a reference to the container
    T& container;
    explicit ContainerContainer(T& container)
      : container{container}
    {}
};

template <typename T>
struct ContainerContainer<T, true>
{
    // rvalue version: move-constructs a new copy of container
    const T container;
    explicit ContainerContainer(T container)
      : container{std::move(container)}
    {}
};
```

```
template <typename Container>
class ReverseContainerView : ContainerContainer<Container>
{
    using Base = ContainerContainer<Container>;
public:
    explicit ReverseContainerView(Container&& container)
        : Base{std::forward<Container>(container)}
    {}

    auto begin() {
        using std::rbegin;
        return rbegin(Base::container);
    }
    auto end() {
        using std::rend;
        return rend(Base::container);
    }
};


template<typename Container>
auto Reverse(Container&& container)
{
    return ReverseContainerView<Container>(std::forward<Container>(container));
}
```

```
// test program
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    int list[] = {1, 2, 3};
    for (auto& i: Reverse(list)) {
        std::cout << ++i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    const auto const_list = {1, 2, 3}; // initializer_list
    for (auto& i: Reverse(const_list)) {
        // ++i; ERROR: 'i' is read-only
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    for (auto& i: Reverse(std::vector<int>{10, 20, 30})) {
        // ++i; ERROR: 'i' is read-only
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

---

From C++17 onwards, we don't really need the `Reverse()` helper function: we can instead simply provide a template deduction guide:

```
template<typename Container>
explicit ReverseContainerView(Container&& container)
    -> ReverseContainerView<Container>;
```

We might want to choose a shorter name for the class now that it's more visible to the users.

Comment: excellent improvements! I have a question though, why didn't we capture/store by rvalue reference in the `ContainerContainer` (the rvalue variant of it) ?

Comment: If we're given an rvalue reference, we need to copy it.  If we just keep a reference to a temporary value, the reference will be invalid once the value is destructed (and that's before the `for` loop calls `begin()`).  If you (or anyone) has suggestions on how I can improve the sentence where I explain that, please add a comment or make a suggested edit.

Comment: indeed it makes sense. how about a const ref, shouldn't it prolong the lifetime of the temporary? I know it doesn't make sense to keep it as a const ref in this context but just for the sake of trying I think I did that the other day and I was still left with a dangling ref

Comment: Const ref doesn't work, because the lifetime extension isn't transitive.  See [Does a const reference class member prolong the life of a temporary?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2784262) over on [so].